# SQL TRANSLATION TO LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have a problem with this SQL sentence:

```
SELECT     DOCUMENTOS.*
FROM         DOCUMENTOS 
INNER JOIN
                      DOCUMENTOS_NOTARIOS ON DOCUMENTOS.uniCODOBJ = DOCUMENTOS_NOTARIOS.UNICODDOC 
INNER JOIN
                      NOTARIOS ON DOCUMENTOS_NOTARIOS.UNICODNOT = NOTARIOS.uniCODOBJ
Where notarios.unicodobj = '84B11CDE-1C4B-4D0F-8C68-A54074B8D652'
```

I would to pass to LINQ for entity framework and I need the results into IQueryable list

I Tried this but I don't know how to pass to IQueryable list,

```
List<DOCUMENTOS> DocumentosByNotarioList = new List<DOCUMENTOS>();
                var query = from d in db.DOCUMENTOS
                            join dn in db.DOCUMENTOS_NOTARIOS on d.uniCODOBJ equals dn.UNICODDOC
                            join n in db.NOTARIOS on dn.UNICODNOT equals n.uniCODOBJ
                            where n.uniCODOBJ == test
                            select new
                            {
                                d.uniCODOBJ,
                                d.strTITOL,
                                d.strNOMPRO,
                                d.strFECINI,
                                d.strFECFIN
                            };
```

I don't undertand very well this languange I prefer this type...

```
DocumentsList = db.DOCUMENTOS
                    .Where(d => nombre == null || d.strTITOL.Contains(nombre))
                    .Where(d => fechaIni == string.Empty || d.strFECINI.Equals(fechaIni))
                    .Where(d => fechaFin == string.Empty || d.strFECFIN.Equals(fechaFin))
                    .Where(d => tipoLibro == Guid.Empty || d.uniCODSER == tipoLibro)
                    .Where(d => firmaTopo == null || d.strFIRTOP == firmaTopo)
                    .OrderByDescending(d => d.datFECCER).ToList();
```

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Download http://www.linqpad.net/, set it up so you can run the first query.  Then you can click on the tabs below and see the translated version (`.Where()` syntax) and SQL.  It can usually be simplified a tiny bit, but is quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you can't translate anonymous type to DOCUMENTOS tyype. Simply don't do projection:

```
var query = from d in db.DOCUMENTOS
            join dn in db.DOCUMENTOS_NOTARIOS on d.uniCODOBJ equals dn.UNICODDOC
            join n in db.NOTARIOS on dn.UNICODNOT equals n.uniCODOBJ
            where n.uniCODOBJ == test
            select d;

var DocumentosByNotarioList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I don't Understand very well.
I have this function because i'm working with MVC and i need this iqueryable for pass to the view

Comment: @user2564914 sorry, I don't understand you - what stops you from passing this to view? BTW why you need queryable? Pass list

Answer (score 0):

I don't Understand very well.
I have this function because i'm working with MVC and i need this iqueryable for pass to the view, this view contains one infragistics grid..

```
public static IQueryable<DOCUMENTOS> GetDocumentosByNotario()
            {
                Guid test = new Guid("84B11CDE-1C4B-4D0F-8C68-A54074B8D652");
                netCNCEntities db = new netCNCEntities();
                List<DOCUMENTOS> DocumentosByNotarioList = new List<DOCUMENTOS>();

                var query = from d in db.DOCUMENTOS
                            join dn in db.DOCUMENTOS_NOTARIOS on d.uniCODOBJ equals dn.UNICODDOC
                            join n in db.NOTARIOS on dn.UNICODNOT equals n.uniCODOBJ
                            where n.uniCODOBJ == test
                            select d;

                var DocumentosByNotarioList = query.ToList();
}
```

Thanks a lot for this help!!!